# Convert a CERT/PEM certificate to a PFX certificate

Tags: certificate

I've seen a couple questions about how to convert a PFX to a cert file, but I need to go the other way.

I have two files:

> bob_cert.cert
>
> bob_key.pem

I'd like to convert them to a single .pfx file.  Is there a tool that does this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/9717/3202 is a great explanation about cert file formats, just fyi

Comment: This is my gist for a list of common key/certificate formats and conversion commands: https://gist.github.com/tuansoibk/0b1f279be5c1b782d95f4e15af1442cb

Answer (score 562, accepted):

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey bob_key.pem -in bob_cert.cert -export -out bob_pfx.pfx
```

Comment: How can i achieve the same thing programmatically in C#?

Comment: check MSDN. it has great examples for doing so in C#.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of these examples?  I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Windows version of OpenSSL is available at http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.  Just tried it, and it worked properly for this purpose.

Comment: Great list of common OpenSSL commands at https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Comment: One thing for creating PFX files for Microsoft's Authenticode `signtool`: use some password for the exported key (or e.g. `.p12` certificate + key file). Somehow an empty password doesn't work. (or maybe it should then be `signtool /p "" ...` - or something along those lines. Besides, when exporting in Windows' "Internet Options" the password is required.

Comment: where to run this command in window? I try it on command prompt but not working their

Comment: maybe correct key file name wouldn't be `bob_key.pem` but `bob_key.key`

Comment: A couple of additions: `-name "friendly name"` sets the name (which would appear in certificate list in Windows, for example), and `-certfile cacert.pem` can be used to add the CA certificate(s) and produce the `.pfx` file with the whole chain.

Comment: Hmmm... I needed to reverse `-inkey` and `-in` parameters to make this work. `-inkey` for the private key and `-in` for the `.pem`.

Comment: @RickStrahl: the .pem extension is used for lots of things, including both keys _and_ certs, but _in this Q_ key.pem is the key and cert.cert is the cert, so it is actually doing the same as you and both are correct.

Comment: @ataraxia: the gnuwin32 openssl is _way_ obsolete; slproweb as already suggested above is up to date, and also follows Windows packaging conventions correctly making it easier to use.

Comment: I'm very disappointed that this has 387 up votes and it's entirely UNHELPFUL to anyone who doesn't realize you need to install OpenSSL for this to work.  A proper answer should include context and information, not just a copy/paste of some command with no instructions or details.

Comment: it is asking for export password .. is it absolutely necessary to give any password ?

Comment: for those people having trouble with running this command, you can use git bash to run this.

Comment: I was using git bash and this command was hanging.  It turns out that my certs expected a password.  In this case you MUST prepend "winpty" to your command.  so in git bash it would look like: [winpty openssl pkcs12 -inkey bob_key.pem -in bob_cert.cert -export -out bob_pfx.pfx].  This may be the same for run environments.

Comment: Hello, i have 4 .pem files cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem can i convert all this to a single pfx file? is that the way to go?

Comment: If you get the "Password required" error, put this at the end of the statement:  -password pass:somepwd  ..which results in this: openssl pkcs12 -inkey bob_key.pem -in bob_cert.cert -export -out bob_pfx.pfx -password pass:somepwd

Answer (score 52):

I created .pfx file from .key and .pem files.

Like this `openssl pkcs12 -inkey rootCA.key -in rootCA.pem -export -out rootCA.pfx`

That's not the direct answer but still maybe it helps out someone else.

Comment: How is this different than Francis's answer from 2009? Essentially the same command.

Answer (score 37):

Here is how to do this on Windows without third-party tools:

1. **Import certificate to the certificate store.** In Windows Explorer select "Install Certificate" in context menu.
   [image]
   Follow the wizard and accept default options "Local User" and "Automatically".
2. **Find your certificate in certificate store.** On Windows 10 run the "Manage User Certificates" MMC. On Windows 2013 the MMC is called "Certificates". On Windows 10 by default your certificate should be under "Personal"->"Certificates" node.
3. **Export Certificate.** In context menu select "Export..." menu:
   [image]

   Select "Yes, export the private key":
   [image]

   You will see that .PFX option is enabled in this case:
   [image]

   Specify password for private key.

Comment: In step 2, my certificate don't  "Personal"->"Certificates". It appears in  "Other People"->"Certificates", and when exporting, the "Personal Information Exchange (PFX)" appears disabled. Do you know how to enable it?

Comment: I fixed with the portable certificate converter from DigiCert: https://www.digicert.com/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm

Comment: you cannot import a PEM.

Comment: You need to rename .pem to .cer first in order for Windows to recognize the file as a certificate/private key file. Both file extensions may contain  cert(s) and/or key(s) in either ASCII-armored plaintext or Base64/DER encoded binary format, but you can use cer files with Windows built-in utilities.

Comment: OP's question was how to import it when the private key is not included in the certificate file but you got two files: a crt and a pem (pem containing the private key). This answer doesn't work in that case.

Comment: The elephant in the room here, as already pointed out, windows won't recognize pem files and (as was also pointed out) renaming it to crt won't solve the problem OP had,

BTW, you didn't mention anywhere in your answer you're supposed to rename the .pem file.

Comment: Downvote reason: Answer is totally wrong and doesn't address the question in any way.

Comment: @Gabrielizalo, the link is dead. Can you please update it?

Comment: @Bigeyes I think this is the updated link: https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm

Comment: I'm not getting the "export private key" select window, then I have the .PFX option greyed out

Answer (score 7):

If you have a self-signed certificate generated by `makecert.exe` on a Windows machine, you will get two files: `cert.pvk` and `cert.cer`. These can be converted to a pfx using `pvk2pfx`

`pvk2pfx` is found in the same location as `makecert` (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` or similar)

```
pvk2pfx -pvk cert.pvk -spc cert.cer -pfx cert.pfx
```