# Windows Azure Web Role Certificate Error

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I need to create a Web Role in Azure with an https endpoint with a real SSL certificate (not self-signed). So I need my own domain, which I have, and have pointed it at my "me.cloudapp.net" URL via a CNAME in my hoster's DNS.

I have purchased a certificate for that domain also. I need to upload that into my Azure portal for the web role, but I can't - Azure gives me an error when I try.

The certificate came in the form of 2 zip files (I'm new to buying certs). One zip has 3 .crt files, and the other has 1 .cer file. Azure requires a .cer or .pfx, so I tried the .cer. It fails with the error "The certificate is not valid, or the password is incorrect."

There is a .crt file in the zip folder that has 3 files that has the same name as the .cer file. If I change the extension of this .crt file to .cer, it will upload, but when I try to publish my deployment, I get the error

"Certificate with thumbprint 3329398FB72BFCC7EF89C90B950D722C6047C2A1 associated with HTTPS input endpoint EndpointForThat does not contain private key. The long running operation tracking ID was: 010a29856c1948f39e71620446223b4e.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first complete the certificate request process on the machine from which you initiated the request. The process for doing this varies by technology stack. Here is a page from [Comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=view&parentcategoryid=95&nav=0,96,1) on how to install certificates on various platforms.

After you have completed the request on the machine that initiated it, then you can export the certificate. That new file is what you need to upload to Azure.

Comment: Thanks Natahn, that was my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For HTTPS endpoint you need to upload a PFX file.

PFX file is combination of Private Key + Public key.

What you have now is

- .cer - public key
- .crt - private key

You need to combine the `.crt` file that matches the name of `.cer` file into a single .pxf file.

Check [this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-cer-certificate-and-private-key) to get it done.