# Win2008R2 HyperV - create a https Listener with winrm : logon message

Tags: https, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, winrm

i request your help because i am a bit lost,
i try to set up a https Listener for remote management on a Win2208 HyperV

I first try :

```
winrm quickconfig -transport:https
```

i issue the error :

```
Cannot create a WinRM listener on HTTPS because this machine does not have an appropriate certificate. To be used for SSL, a certificate must have a CN matching the hostname, be appropriate for Server Authentication, and not be expired, revoked, or self- signed.
```

like suggest by some papers, i use the next command to get more suitable informations :

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="SERVER1";CertificateThumbprint="1d9256aea461788764cec1904463120f094393f9"}
```

and got message:

```
"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."
```

I know my certificate is ok, because i have add to fix EKU and CN to match HOSTNAME  according previous failure Message… But i do not understand this last one ? and how to fix.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my response... i was missing the privatekey during the export/import.

This fix the problem ..

now guys, if you encoutered this message :
"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Check if you have the privatekey embeded with tour certificate !!!!1

Comment: Thank you for getting back and posting an answer! More info: you probably need a pfx file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307886/2604492