# WCF client SOAP webservice p7b certificate private key

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF client with customBinding and mtomSOAPMessage Soap11. I got a certificate in P7B format from CA which was requested using a CSR generated using OpenSSL. I see this p7b certificate doesn't have a private key linked.

How do I point my WCF configuration to this certificate for signing messages with private key?

Comment: You have to merge CA response (p7b) with private key generated by OpenSSL during request generation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-cer-certificate-and-private-key

Comment: So I have to get cer from p7b and using openssl generate pfx?

Comment: Exactly. Further, you should use native tools on Windows (certreq.exe) OS, instead of OpenSSL.