# WPF Application Deployment using ClickOnce with trust certificate

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have deployed my WPF Application using test certificate to production. Now, I have to change the test certificate and purchase a new Certificate.

I have gone through MSDN sites and i am not able to conclude what to do?
So, I need the clarification about the following

1. *Where to purchase these certificate files and what type certificate it is?*
2. *Do we have to install those certificate on client's system ?*
3. *What will be the format of this certificate ? Pfx?*
4. *If i deploy again using the trusted certificate, it will cause any problem with updating the application that have deployed by test certificate?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where to purchase these certificate files and what type certificate it is?

From a trusted authority such as for example Verisign.  You sign your application with a `.pfx` file that you may create using the Pvk2Pfx.exe tool. Please refer to the following links for more information about this.

**How to use VeriSign Certificate in Click Once Deployment:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/506409fc-979b-41fd-855a-70da2963877b/how-to-use-verisign-certificate-in-click-once-deployment?forum=winformssetup

**You’ve Got a New Verisign Authenticode Certificate – Now What?:** https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/03/youve-got-a-new-verisign-authenticode-certificate-now-what/

[How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key)

> Do we have to install those certificate on client's system ?

Yes, the certificate used to sign a ClickOnce application must be configured in the Trusted Publishers certificate store on the user's machine. Please refer to Brian Noyes' MSDN article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx.

> If i deploy again using the trusted certificate, it will cause any problem with updating the application that have deployed by test certificate?

It depends. The users may have to uninstall the application and install the new version with the new signing certificate. Please refer to this MSDN article for details.

**Certificate Expiration in ClickOnce Deployment:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx

Comment: So, 'MS Authenticode Certificate' is the one to purchase from Verisign?