# Certificate is not trusted. Application's installer sometimes works correctly and others fails

Tags: visual-studio, installation, certificate, vsto

I have an application in a test environment and when I install it in my computer all work correctly, but when others users installs it some of them works and others fails. When it fails, it displays this error: customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for **appname** o its locations is not trusted. Contact your administrators for further assistance.

In addition, I created a test certificate, using visual studio 2015, to sing the application. The application is an add-in using VSTO.

The app is downloaded from a web server into my company, also it uses two web services.

[Here is a photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGiFf.png)

Comment: Get a proper certificate or install the certificate you used onto the computers that you want this app to trust. The whole concept of having to sign the cert is to prevent accidental installations of untrusted applications. In order for that to work the machines you're installing to need to first trust the cert.

Comment: [Granting Trust to Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx)

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks for your answer. Which certificate do I need to sign this application? I have SSL certificate in my web server where the app is downloaded.

Comment: You need a Code Sign Certificate https://www.google.nl/search?q=code+sign+certificate&oq=code+sign+certificate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a proper certificate or install the certificate you used onto the computers that you want this app to trust. The whole concept of having to sign the cert is to prevent accidental installations of untrusted applications. In order for that to work the machines you're installing to need to first trust the cert.

You will need a [Code Signing certificate](https://www.google.nl/search?q=code%20sign%20certificate) and sign the Click-Once package using that cert. You may still need to distribute the trusted cert to the machines somehow (depending on how those are setup).

Comment: Hello @jessehouwing , thank you for your help. I got a Code Signing certificate, it is a .cert file. When I try to use it is visual studio I need a .pfx file.  How can I get a .pfx file from my original certificate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing. I really appreciate your help.