# Is it possible to use mixed SSL certificate

Tags: azure, openssl, azure-virtual-machine

I have a requirement where my application on a Linux Virtual machine create certificate in crt format but as fronted load balancer I am using Azure's application gateway which uses pfx certificate ? is this possible to let application create its crt certificate but convert them using openssl utility to pfx and use it in front end load balancer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you need know your certificate private key.

You will need to use openssl.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt
```

You also could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key).

Comment: The different between pfx and crt, you could check this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29425/difference-between-pfx-and-cert-certificates).