# How to create pfx file if you have private key(.key) given by your client

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-10

Actually, I have a private key given by my client

> -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----XYZ-------------------------END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

And I have to create an SSL Certificate for a given domain.

Please help me out with how to proceed. I am unable to understand what to do with this private key.

I know how to generate csr file from IIS but still I am unable to understand the use private key given by my client for SSL certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key)

Comment: What is your role in this relationship? If you are not a CA but would like to offer certificates, then you can only create self signed certificates (Google openssl and so on to learn the concepts). If your role is to apply the certificate on behave of your client, you need to use the private to generate a certificate request, and submit to a CA.