# How to provide https for a domain in ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, https

I have been trying to add https to my website, which is bound to a domain. Therefore, I tried certbot to generate
my certificates. I have tested those certificates on my mock server written in js. There, all I had to do was provide specific options to Express server like following:

```
var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem')
};
```

Poof, a lock appeared at my browser's link tab, saying my website is secure. Now I wanted to move it to ASP.NET Core, so I found kestrel options, where I can provide my certificate:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{  
    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
    {
        o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(ohttps =>
        {
            ohttps.ClientCertificateMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
            ohttps.ServerCertificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(...);
        });
    });
});
```

However it seems like I only have to provide X509 Certificate, which is a public certificate. Isn't a private certificate needed for server to provide safe connection? Do I have to use a private certificate? How to implement it in ASP.NET Core? (3.1)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#with-openssl

Answer (score 1):

I'm configuring the Kestrel HTTPS options with .UseKestrel. But the options can also be set in the .ConfigureKestrel method.

In the example, I'm loading the cert from a Windows Servers certificate store.

But there is also an overload of `UseHttps(ListenOptions, String, String)` which accepts a filename and a password. ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.listenoptionshttpsextensions.usehttps?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions_UseHttps_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_ListenOptions_System_String_System_String_)
)

```
new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel(opt =>
{
        int port = endpointConfig.Port;
        opt.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps(GetCertificateFromStore(certThumbprint, certStore));
        });
})
.ConfigureServices(
    services => services
        .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
.UseUrls(url)
.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [johnmoarr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13804454/johnmoarr) answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284371/13308476) I was able to figure this out.
Key provided to *.UseHttps()* method must be public key paired up with private key, which can be achieved by generating it with openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out key.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in fullchain.pem
```

Then, the generated file **key.pfx** can be used in kestrel builder method, along with password provided in certificate export:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(o =>
        {
            o.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, opt =>
            {
                 opt.UseHttps("YOUR_PATH/key.pfx", "YOUR_EXPORT_PASSWORD");
            });
        });
    });
```

Furthermore, you can even test it on your local computer, putting your LAN IP and domain name in hosts file.