# Loading X509 certificate issue in net core

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I have a issue loading x509 certificate in net.core.
I use the following code :

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

and I get the following error :

```
Cannot find the requested object
```

If I change the code to :

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(_path);
```

I get thrown the following exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException : X509Certificate is immutable on this 
platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead.
```

Other useful infos:

- Certificate_path": "C:\XYZ\Documents\XYZ\rsakey.txt
- Certificate and alghoritm info : RSA encryption strategy with mode ECB, padding PKCS1Padding and KeyLength 1024 is used to encrypt data at client side.

I discovered that I'm trying to pass a public key instead of a certificate but I don't know how can I generate certificate in c# from a public key. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What is your certificatePath value ? What certificate extension you are trying to import ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I completed the post with the required info.

Comment: imo you should create an .pfx file from your cert and key, and then try to create `X509Certificate2` by giving path to .pfx file. 
You might find something usefull about that process under this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key

Comment: Does rsakey.txt say something inside like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`?  Or is it perhaps instead `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`?  The latter two, for example, aren't valid as certificates.

Comment: @bartonjs you're right. It isn't a certificate but a public key.  How can I generate certificate from a public key?