# Generating PFX file from crt and pem file

Tags: openssl, certificate, pfx

I have following files:

- root.crt
- intermediate1.crt
- intermediate2.crt
- privatekey.pem

I tried to generate a pfx file with openssl

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in root.crt -certfile intermediate1.crt -certfile intermediate2.crt`

Which gives me following error:

```
No cert in -in file 'root.crt' matches private key
68310000:error:05800074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:crypto\x509\x509_cmp.c:405:
```

Is there something wrong with my private key?

Comment: Does privatekey.pem corresponds to root.crt? Private key specified with -inkey <file> should match the cert specified with -in <file>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key)

Comment: @SujayKumar Yes, the private key was not matching with the crt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root.crt was not matching with the private key. After using the correct crt file it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Private key specified with '-inkey file' should match the cert specified with '-in file'.