# How can I upload .crt and .key file when making a Restsharp request?

Tags: c#, .net, https, ssl-certificate, restsharp

I have specified a host by uploading my .crt and .key files to the certificates section of the settings tab for Postman, and I have no problem making requests through postman. However, when requesting with restsharp, I am getting an error even though I add the certificate as follows. I was able to add .crt and .key files in Postman, but only .crt in code. The error message I got was "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." shaped. How can I add .crt and .key files to restsharp when making requests from within the code? If .crt is sufficient why am I getting this error?

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://uri");
options.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
options.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\name.crt"));
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(options);
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/token", requestModel.Method);
RestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

Comment: And what Is the inner exception?

Comment: Innerexception in order;
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

Comment: Check the TLS version used un both client and server

Comment: Where can I do this? In addition, do I need to add to the code for TLS?

Comment: You can add tls 1.2 but for sure Is the default. You can check this in the cert info

Comment: The certificate shows as TLS1.2. I get the same error even though I add TLS1.2 to the code side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key can be included by [combining the .crt & .key files into one Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key).

Then instead of passing the .crt file, pass the .pfx file...

```cs
options.ClientCertificates.Add(
    new X509Certificate2(@"C:\name.pfx", "password_for_pfx"));
```