# Signing windows .NET executable

Tags: .net, code-signing

Recently our company bought Thawte authenticode certificate. Now I'm trying to sign very simple hello-world .NET console application.

I use

> signtool.exe signwizard

1. choose my .exe
2. choose certificate from file. I select `.crt` file. All info about cert is ok - there are attributes of our company
3. then I'm suggested to choose private key. I've saved private key when I've generated Certificate Request file `.csr`.I select it - `.key` file.
   [image]
4. Click `Next` and then goes error saying that "Certificate and private key don't match or contain invalid info"

I verified that my private key match certificate according to that post [Verifying that a Private Key Matches a Certificate](https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064) and all seems fine - modulus and public exponent are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to sign executable using generated `.pfx` file.

This is how `.pfx` is created from `cert` and `private key` - [create pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate)

Then I've used signtool -

> signtool.exe sign /f your.pfx /p pfxpassword `<exe.file>`

And it was signed!

Again, it is with `.pfx` file which needs to be created first.