# How to import an OpenSSL key file into the Windows Certificate Store

Tags: windows, openssl, x509, schannel

I've got an OpenSSL generated X.509 certificate in PEM format and it's associated key file. This certificate is required for authentication when connecting to a prototype server. This works fine on Linux. I've been using the Microsoft SChannel API to drive SSL/TLS connections on Windows platforms but I want to use the same test certificate. I can right-click on the certificate file and import it into my certificate store but I believe that the private key is not imported with it (even though I've concatenated them into the same file).

When I go to run the SChannel code, I get a 'SEC_E_NO_CREDENTIALS' error when I init the security context (via InitializeSecurityContext). I suspect this means that the private key is missing.

Does anyone know how to test the presence or absence of a private key in a certificate which is located in the Personal (or 'My') certificate store, accessed via 'certmgr.msc'?. Is it possible to import a new key file for a certificate in the store?

Any insight or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What a cute puzzle, I'm still trying to find the C++ question in there...

Comment: Fair point, I've removed the tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To test if private key is installed for the certificate, double click the certificate icon in certmgr.msc. If it has private key, it will show a message in the property page that you have private key, otherwise it will not give any reference the the private key.

[image: Certificate with a private key]

---

To import the certificate with its private key, you can do the following:

1. Pack the certificate and its private key into a PKCS #12 file or PFX file using openssl pkcs12. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate).
2. Import this PKCS #12 or PFX file into the certificate store.

Note that you may see errors when importing the pfx file, such as 'This file is invalid for use as the following: Personal Information Exchange'. This error was caused by the certificate lacking to appropriate X.509 v3 extensions (such as the usage fields (digital signature, etc))

Comment: I got that error on a test certificate. So, I corrected the certificate. In case you got the error, get it reissued.

Comment: Note, it creates the file even if there is a problem. I missed an error message during the combining of the cert with the private key file. It didn't find one of the files.