# what is different between public keys

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, public-key

I have tried to create a public key in two ways,

1. I created Self Signed Certificate and export it to .pfx file and used Openssl to get temp.cer file which contains the public key
2. used openssl to generate a public key as follows.

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out myjira.pem 1024

   openssl rsa -in temp.pem -pubout -out temp.pub
   ```

I am using an application and trying to implement OAuth on it. when I enter the public key from temp.cer (which is longer) it does not accepts it and says 
*Must be a valid public key. java.security.InvalidKeyException:*. But when I enter the public key from temp.pub (which is  much shorter than the other one) it accepts it.
now my question is what is differences between those public keys?

Answer (score 1):

A certificate file contains a public key as well as identity information that is bound to that key via a signature.  That's why your certificate file is longer than your public key file.

If you load the certificate into a Java [X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) object, you can obtain the PublicKey by using the `getPublicKey()` method of the `X509Certificate` object.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I loaded the .cer file into X509Certificate2. It has a public key as you said, but it does not has any private key. Is it possible to create a .cer file from my .pub and .pem file so that it contains both private and public key?

Comment: My prolem is Jira, I am trying to implement OAut. Jira accepts public key and it accepts ONLY a public key that is generated by openssl rsa -in temp.pem -pubout -out temp.pub. and my oauth client must use the private key. I have to create a .pfx file from a public key and a private key to load it by using X509Certificate which loads a .pfx file

Comment: @user217648, Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate) on creating pfx files from a key and cert.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the longer of your keys is in fact a private key. Generally you have a key pair, a private and public key.

more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: usually .cer files containing public keys, isn't it? .cer file cotains -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----