# How to load self-signed certificate into certificate store

Tags: openssl, certificate, windows-7-x64, crt

I want to load a self-signed certificate created by OpenSSL to the local windows cert storage.

```
OpenSSL: 1.0.1l 

OS: Windows 7 N
```

I created the certificate with the OpenSSL library and used the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.key 2048

openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycert.crt
```

Now i tried to load the certificate into the storage via `mmc.exe` but it failed for the following reason:

`"The file type not identifiable. Choose another file"` *(It's not the original text because I am not using english on my OS.)*

I tried this with every "*acceptable*" file type.

So my thoughts were that Windows wants the key and the cert merged together. I don't know how certificates in Windows getting handled internally. (I know it's bullshit to provide private key in a certificate but i just kept trying.)

So i tried this to merge the files: (According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate).)

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey mykey.key -in mycert.crt export -out outputfile.crt/pkcs ...
```

But then the following error occurred:

```
unable to load certificates
```

Seems not working. Any suggestions how I can load certificate the local storage?

Also I would like to know if its possible to create a machine-certificate (`PeterPan-PC` or `192.168.2.1` instead of the Windows username (`PeterPan`)) with OpenSSL?

**UPDATE:**

With the following command a `certificate request` was created:

```
openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycert.crt
```

By using the following command, a `self-signed certificate` will be created and the issue is solved:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key mykey.key -out mycert.crt -days 365
```

Comment: openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycert.crt creates a certificate signing request and not a certificate. You can follow http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html to create a self signed certificate(upto step 4)

Comment: You are fully right. I already solved the issue.. but I unforunatly forgot to update my question. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: ok great.  Added it as an answer as it fixed ur issue. @Leviathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycert.crt` creates a certificate signing request and not a certificate. You can follow http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html to create a self signed certificate(upto step 4)