# Sign clickonce application

Tags: c#, clickonce, signing

I got delivered a certificate from a company, and got the .cer file, however I am not able select from a .cer file but it needs a .pfx. Does anyone know how I can sign my clickonce application using a .cer file?

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

You must use [signtool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx). I usually add a post build event to sign the release configuration output.