# Given an encrypted .key file and a password. I need to secure them on an Azure site C# MVC 5 (.NET 4.6)

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, chilkat

I have an encrypted "RSA PRIVATE KEY" ".key" RSA PKCS#1 key (which [I understand from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065522/2440976)) does not include a key type OID).

I also have the password to decrypt it. I am using it to create an encrypted and signed URL.

I have managed to get the code working locally, but now I need to figure how to secure it on an Azure web app (I'm using C# MVC 5 with .NET Framework 4.6 and a SQL Server back end). I was helped along by [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098089/2440976), but it is an older link that either I can't figure out how to use or it's longer valid. Azure seems to only allow me to upload a .pfx file.

Comment: Is this for an https cert or something? You've explained this very poorly

Comment: @JoePhillips - Thanks for the critique - Does the new explanation clear this up? I'm trying to not go into much detail (due to the secure nature of the info.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553149/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-key-file-to-a-pfx Try this and then update your question with more details. You may have to research how to do the same checks on windows (unless you have access to linux)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to use it for you could use Azure Key Vault to store the secure key safely.

If you want to use the key to enable SSL then you probably need to do as suggested in comments and convert it to pfx-format and then upload it to the App Service.

[Azure Key Vault can store your key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/about-keys--secrets-and-certificates#BKMK_KeyTypes) and you can control access to it with [role-based security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault) in Azure. [Import your key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importkey) to the Key Vault and then [access it securely from your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application).