# 140568388757144:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04, private-key

I am new to digital sign. I was trying to create my own Certificate Authority and generate certificate using that. I am following [these](https://workaround.org/certificate-authority/) steps.

I Created a private key (.key) and a certificate request (.req). However, when I tried to sign that request with the CA’s key and create a certificate (.crt) with the  command `/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -sign`, I am getting this error:

```
Using configuration from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
unable to load CA private key
140568388757144:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY Signed certificate is in newcert.pem
```

Note: I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`. *demoCA* directory, *newkey.pem* and *newreq.pem* are being created in `/home`.

I need `.pfx` or `.p12` file so that I can use that to sign pdf.

If I am missing something please suggest steps.

Comment: Did you find answer for this?

Comment: Not exactly. But maybe this will help- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate"

I can't remember exactly what I did but found some workaround for sure. There may be some software which gives you the desired file...
Sorry can't be much of a help.