# Generate PFX file using PEM file with private key data in text format

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have the certificate in P7B format and along with I have private key data in text file format as below. Can anyone please help how can I generate the PFX certificate using this data?

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
// Long Encrypted text
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and should be offtopic, but has been asked and answered long before topicality was developed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert PKCS#7 (P7B) to PEM:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in a.p7b -out a.cer
```

2. Merge KEY and PEM to PKCS#12 (PFX)

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out a.pfx -inkey a.key -in a.cer"
```