# Configure SSL certificate for Kestrel WebHost builder In .NET Console App

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, kestrel

I'm creating an ASP.NET Web API endpoint inside a console app which I need to host as a Windows Service.

Now everything is working except the endpoint is in http. I want to use https.

When I run it via Visual Studio.

I believe the Kestrel is behind an IIS as a reverse proxy and SSL certificates are validated. But when I host it as a Windows service. I'm getting certificate errors when trying to reach the endpoint

This is my Kestrel WebHost builder

```
var configigurations = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                       .Build();
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("sslcertificate.pfx", "ssl@123");
                    });
                })
                .UseUrls(config.ApiBaseUrl)
                .UseConfiguration(configigurations)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
host.Run();
```

Since it runs as a Windows service and exposes the API, I cannot rely on IIS. I need to configure for Kestrel.

But how can I

1. Generate an SSL for localhost (I'm using Windows)
2. If I have already an SSL certificate in production (*.cert). How can I make a *.pfx (cert + RSA private key) from it on production server (also Windows)

Comment: Okay so it's a console app. but inside it there is an API endpoint. Right? And when you run it in VisualStudio it hits the endpoint and when deployed as a Windows service it throws cert validation error. This is your issue right?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to install it on my local system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a certificate

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p crypticpassword
```

This will create a trust

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 1):

1. .Net Core (and .Net 5) is bundled with a convenient tool to handle development self-signed certificates. Look into [dotnet dev-certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#with-dotnet-dev-certs). The commands are:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p crypticpassword
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This doc also describes how to do the same thing with PowerShell or openssl if that's your style

2. Look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate). In short, you can do that by exporting certificate from Windows Certificate store and choosing "Yes, export Private key" which automatically enabled PFX format