# Using ECDSA code signing certificate for clickOnce

Tags: visual-studio, encryption, clickonce

Has anyone experience or been able to code sign EXEs with ECDSA, while trying at the min, we are getting a Cannot find key error?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a CERT/PEM certificate to a PFX certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate)

Comment: You can try doing it with signtool.exe, here is the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-sign-setup-files-with-signtool-exe-clickonce?view=vs-2019)